# GSA how to find the unclicked urls?

Tags: google-search, google-search-appliance

In GSA, how can i find the un-clicked url from the result page. So that i remove that particular URL from indexing. The reason our license almost full.

NOTE:We are not using ASR for search.

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Taking this kind of approach is not going to work.  If your license is full and you add URLs to the "Do Not Crawl" list you are just going to end up with a long list of URLs not to include and likely run into issues in the near term.

You are better off to look at the content side, see which content has never been viewed and consider deleting it from the content side or implementing "robots noindex" rules on it.

You mention you are not using ASR so you really have no capability from the GSA side to determine what has not been clicked.  ASR is the only feature that tracks this.

Comment: I agree with Terry.  You don't know what you don't know.  The GSA will also use Page Rank to remove some of the urls when you eventually go over.

Answer (score 1):

Using ASR will tell you which URLs are clicked but working out which ones are not is a bit more tricky. You need a report over a good length of time telling you which URLs have been clicked that you can use along with the Admin console Export URLs function to work out which ones have not.

If you haven't been tracking this data for a good length of time then this info is not easy to work out.

Have you thought about increasing your licence?